# Add specific Button with Control constructor?

Tags: c#, winforms

I know this might a simple question, but is there a way to add a Button (or other controls) to a Windows Form in just one line? Something like:

```
// Control constructor: new Control(string text, int left, int top, int x, int y)

Control.Add(new Control("Press me!", 100, 100, 40, 40) as Button);
```

since I want to use the Control constructor to define both the button's size and position on the form.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use property initializers when constructing an object:

```
Controls.Add(
    new Button    
    {
       Text = "Press me",
       Left = 400,
       // initialize any properties you wish
    });
```

Comment: You can even do the whole thing in the initializer. Instead of wrapping a `Controls.Add` around the whole thing, just add another property assignment to the initializer: `Parent = this`. It looks a little odd (a `new` expression not being assigned to anything) but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but first you have to create Button class instance and then add it to the Controls collection. For example like this:

```
var button = new Button();
button.Name = "btnTest";
button.Size = new Size(10,10);
```

and then:

```
Controls.Add(button);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though I know how to do that, I just want to avoid using lots of lines / methods to add a button. Thanks though.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Ilya Kogan has shown a bit smaller version :)